# Excel Named Range Formula - Not Automatic Updating

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a table in Excel that has column heading names (e.g. data_type1, data_type2, etc.). The data in this table changes based on parameters entered on another sheet, and they are pulled to charts which update dynamically.

As a convenience to a user who might be using this sheet I have added a 'user specified function' (non-vba) which also plots to one of the charts. By user specified function I mean I have three cells with dropdown lists. Two correspond to the table headings and one has a short list of operations that can be applied between the two selected data types (e.g. a user might select 'dataype1', '+', 'datatype2' which would produce a sum of the two in the final column of my table).

The user specified function is achieved by defining a named 'range/function' to match the drop downs with their respective column headers and then calls evaluate. See below:

```
=EVALUATE("="&ADDRESS(ROW('Raw Data'!XFD5),MATCH(user_in1,'Raw Data'!$A$4:$AF$4,0)) & user_operation & ADDRESS(ROW('Raw Data'!XFD5),MATCH(user_in2,'Raw Data'!$A$4:$AF$4,0)))
```

I name this 'user1_result' and then enter =user1_result in the final column of my table. This approach is nice because it calculates much faster than doing the same thing through building a UDF in VBA and then applying that UDF to every cell in a fairly long column.

Now here is my hangup, this works fine initially, but if the user makes a parameter change that affects one or both of the selected datatypes, the user specified column does not recalculate on-the-fly with the updated data. If the user re-toggles any of the dropdowns the data does recalculate. I am speculating this is from one of two things:
1) Excel does not recognize that a precedent of 'user1_result' has changed, and so for efficiency sake doesn't bother to recompute the column;
2) The 'Evaluate' function used in the named definition of 'user1_result' is not checked for updating, because it's not a normal function (doesn't show up through intellisense if you try to just add that to a cell).

So I am looking for some either confirmation or refutation of these speculations. In the case of confirmation I am hoping to get some advice on how to force the user specified column to update if its precedents change.

One solution is to have VBA do this checking for me and force the computation, but I would like to leave that as a last resort. So, non-VBA solutions preferred.

Comment: "it's not a normal function" - indeed, it's a hack. You're calling `Application.Evaluate` via the formula bar. FWIW a VBA solution would be dead simple if you'd be willing to handle the `Changed` worksheet event to monitor modifications to your *precedents*.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thank you for your clarification on Evaluate! I agree that a VBA solution would be easiest, but a requirement for this tool is that it does not require enabling macros. You've jogged my thought process and I think I have a solution. I've added two things:
A cell with a countif on the first row of data that counts if w/e it doesn't matter. 
A condition that runs user1_result if the countif cell = itself. That way any parameter update triggers the countif, which triggers the conditional, and recalculates.
Thanks for the brain jog!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity I'll answer the above question based on Mat'sMug's feedback:

Regarding the cause of the problem:

The reason the user specified column does not update is because the 'Evaluate' portion of the 'user1_result' named formula is intended to be used at the application level and not as a worksheet function. Because of this, Excel doesn't bother checking to see if its precedents change and ignores it for recalculation.

The problem's solution:

It was suggested to use VBA to watch for worksheet_change events, however, my problem requires that I do NOT use VBA. So, an alternative workaround that forces Excel to check precedents and recalculate the user specified function uses two steps. This functions as a pseudo worksheet_change stand-in.

First, I use a helper cell that performs a countif with an arbitrary counting condition. I don't need it to change, I just need it to share precedents with the inputs of 'user1_result'. So I have it count the number of cells in the first row of data that are larger than some constant:

```
=COUNTIF(A5:AK5,">100000")
```

The result of this computation doesn't matter, but in my case my data have small values and so this returns 0 always.

Second, I use a condition for the computation in the user specified column (the last column in my data table).

```
=IF($AO$1=$AO$1,user1_result)
```

Now, anytime my data table updates, the final column using the named function recomputes. Simple, and if using macros is not viable (for example due to a client/user's security concerns), this can sort of substitute for a worksheet change event.

I hope somebody out there gets use from this!